# Java -Listen for variable changes in different class

Tags: java, android

This is for an Android app using Android Studio.

I have a class that listens to, and handles RFID reader events. 
This is a separate class the the one associated with the activity. The RFID EPC is being read in the class that handles the RFID events, but I want to display this EPC on the UI, but I am not sure how to achieve this.

I have tried implementing ValueSubmittedListener, but not sure how to bind it all together to make it work:

what I have is

```
public class ReadMemoryActivity extends Activity implements 
    View.OnClickListener, ValueSubmittedListener
{
    private TextView txtSelection = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.selection);//where EPC is to be displayed

    public void onSubmitted(String epc)
    {
       txtSelection.setText(epc);
    }
```

and then the class for the Events

```
public class BaseReadAction  implements RfidReaderEventListener 
{
    private List<ValueSubmittedListener> epcListener = new 
    ArrayList<ValueSubmittedListener>();

    public void addListener(ValueSubmittedListener epc)
    {
        epcListener.clear();
        epcListener.add(epc);
    }

    private void notifyListeners()
    {
        for(ValueSubmittedListener epc : epcListener)
        {
            epc.onSubmitted(getSelection());
        }
    }

    public void setSelection(String epc) {

        setEPC = epc;
        notifyListeners();

    }
```

I see there are quite a few listeners out there. had a look at TextWatcher as well, but at a glance it looks like it watches a TextView more than just a string variable. I'm still quite new to android dev and Java in general so my knowledge falls well short of what fits with what.

Answer (score 0):

1. Should be EditText instead of TextView, no?
2. Textwatcher can do a lot:

code:

```
txtSelection.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

   @Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

   @Override    
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int count, int after) {
   }

   @Override    
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int before, int count) {
   }
  });
```

Comment: Yes TextView, my bad. 

Ok so, about this TextWatcher... It will watch what? The TextView?
Because what I am looking for is something to watch / listen to a string value in a different class. 
so String EPC is in class B
when String EPC value changes it will notify class A and the TextView in class A will be populated with the value of String EPC... Class A would be the class that extends Activity, class B is a class that can be used by many other classes.

Answer (score 0):

So this is what I ended up doing to get it to work. 
it is an answer, may not be the best answer, certainly not the only answer but here it is...

in the baseClass I added the following

```
public class BaseReadAction extends Activity  implements 
RfidReaderEventListener {

  private String epcNo;
  private ChangeListener listener;

 public String getEpcNo()
 {
     return epcNo;
 }

 public void setEpcNo(String epc)
 {
     this.epcNo = epc;
     if(listener != null) listener.onChange();
 }

 public ChangeListener getListener() {
     return listener;
 }

 public void setListener(ChangeListener listener) {
     this.listener = listener;
 }


 public interface ChangeListener
 {
     void onChange();
 }
}
```

Then in the UI class in the key_Down event that triggers the scanning I put this.

```
   // listens for event when epc is assigned to variable (ReadAction is an instance of BaseReadAction class
            ReadAction.setListener(new BaseReadAction.ChangeListener(){
            @Override
            public void onChange()
            {
                txtSelection.setText(ReadAction.getEpcNo());//sets the read value to the textView
            }
```